# Fourier series for piecewise f(x)=sign(x) from [-pi..0]=-1 and ]0..Pi]=1

Tags: fourier-transform

[image]

I am trying to compute the coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ when *k* is even then odd. I get a lot of
$\frac{C_i(2^{-\Pi})-C_i(1)}{\pi \ln(2)}$ and others that get more and more complicated, with $C_i$ and $\ln$. Since there is no such thing in the answers that are offered, I am clearly wrong.

[image]

What am I missing?

**Added 20 April 2020**.

The problem arises from a different notation for the functions, among others the trigonometric functions. It was written $\sin(2 k+1) \space x$ which meant in fact $\sin((2k+1) \space x)$. Then I obtained immediately the 3rd response. Sorry for that stupid question. But I read what was suggested in the comments about the homework question. The $C_i$ was the cosine integral, which is written Ci(x). Please, can you delete it completely? I really feel like a fool.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? How are you defining $a_k$ and $b_k$, and how are you calculating them? What is $C_i$ supposed to mean?

Comment: f(x) is an odd function, which brings only 2 possibilities. One of those possibilities does not make sense if k=0.